# Firebase Security Rules - comparing strings of a parameter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to create a collection of "chats" between two users that allows both of them to access the same collection. The collections is a combined set of their Firestore UserIDs ("UID1_UID2"). As such, I've written the security rule to be:

```
match /chats/{combinedUserIDs}/messages{
        allow update, read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == combinedUserIDs[0:27];
        allow update, read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == combinedUserIDs[29:56];
}
```

I try to match by substring but these are not working and I'm getting denied. Am I able to match a parameter with a substring as I have done?

---

Client side code from a call from Flutter (working perfectly if the rule is set to all authenticated users):

```
await firestore
          .collection('chats')
          .document(orderedUserIDs)
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .limit(documentLimit)
          .getDocuments();
```

Comment: Security rules by themselves don't do anything.  Please edit the question to show the client code with the query that isn't working the way you expect.  It should be clear from your question that the rules should either allow or deny the query using the code and document data that they would use.

Comment: @DougStevenson Added the client side code above

Comment: Can you show that the data in the database matches the data you provided in the query?  We can't see that yet.